# ActionScript Flash - Webcam "onFrameChanged" event?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, webcam, augmented-reality

I'm developing a Flash application that works with a web camera.
I want to analyze every frame of the video recording... which is the proper event listener?
This is my actual code:

```
private var video: Video;
private var webcam: Camera;

public function AugmentedReality() {
    webcam = Camera.getCamera();
    if (webcam != null) {
        webcam.setMode(WEB_CAMERA_WIDTH, WEB_CAMERA_HEIGHT, VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);
        video = new Video(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        video.attachCamera(webcam);
        this.addChild(video);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handler);
    }
}

private function handler(aEvent : Event):void {
    // I don't want to use this handler,
    // it is called several times on the same frame if FPS is low
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "analyze every frame of the video recording" but there is the [ActivityEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ActivityEvent.html), for detecting that the camera image has changed since the previous frame:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMotionLevel

There is also quite a lot of work done in [motion detection and motion tracking using Flash/ActionScript](http://www.google.com/search?q=%20actionscript%20motion%20detection%20OR%20tracking) and the Camera object that you can find code examples for.

Comment: It's not important what i want to do after with the single frames, now i just want an handler for detecting frame changing :) i tried ActivityEvent, printing "hello" in the handler... but it prints "hello" just one time, when the camera starts recording :( it should print "hello hello hello hello...", at the FPS speed!

Comment: From the link u pasted: "ActivityEvent (is) dispatched when a camera begins or ends a session". It's not what i need :(

Comment: OK, then I guess you could try to keep using a listener for the Event.ENTER_FRAME event and set the stage.frameRate = webcam.currentFPS.

Comment: well, i could use a timer, it would be the same... i was searching for a more accurate method :)